# Lazy loading a model field's choices

Tags: django

I'm building a Django app to pull in data via an API to track live results of an event with the added ability to override that data before it is displayed.

The first task of the app is to make a request and store the response in the database so I've setup a model;

```
class ApiData(models.Model):
    event = models.CharField(
        _("Event"),
        max_length=100,
    )
    key = models.CharField(
        _("Data identifier"),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("Something to identify the json stored.")
    )
    json = JSONField(
        load_kwargs={'object_pairs_hook': collections.OrderedDict},
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Ideally I would like it so that objects are created in the admin and the save method populates the `ApiData.json` field after creating an API request based on the other options in the object.

Because these fields would have choices based on data returned from the API I wanted to lazy load the choices but at the moment I'm just getting a standard `Charfield()` in my form.
Is this the correct approach for lazy loading model field choices? Or should I just create a custom `ModelForm` and load the choices there? (That's probably the more typical approach I guess)

```
def get_event_choices():
    events = get_events()
    choices = []
    for event in events['events']:
        choices.append((event['name'], event['title']),)
    return choices


class ApiData(models.Model):

    # Fields as seen above

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApiData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field_by_name('event')[0]._choices = lazy(
            get_event_choices, list
        )()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went for a typical approach to get this working by simply defining a form for the model admin to use;

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

from ..models import get_event_choices, ApiData
from ..utils.api import JsonApi

EVENT_CHOICES = get_event_choices()


class ApiDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for collecting the field choices.

    The Event field is populated based on the events returned from the API.
    """
    event = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EVENT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = ApiData

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .forms.apidata import ApiDataForm
from .models import ApiData


class ApiDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ApiDataForm


admin.site.register(ApiData, ApiDataAdmin)
```